# i can't add html divider line

Tags: html, odoo

I am trying to separate my tablet but I cannot add the dividing line, if I put style = "border: 1px solid black in tr it appears to me but not in the way I want.

The code is the following:

```
 <template id="diario_report">
    tr.border_bottom td {
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
   <table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%" cellspacing="0">                 
   <tbody style="border: 1px solid black">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border:1px solid black;width:20%;text-align:center"><strong>Fecha</strong></td>
                            <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black;width:20%;text-align:center"><strong>Cuentas</strong></td>
                            <td style="border:1px solid black;width:20%;text-align:center"><strong>Debe</strong></td>
                            <td style="border:1px solid black;width:20%;text-align:center"><strong>Haber</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="val">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:center"><t t-esc="val.get('fecha')"/></td>
                                <td style="text-align:center"><t t-esc="val.get('titulo')"/></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td style="text-align:center"><t t-esc="val.get('total_debe')"/></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td><td></td>
                                <td style="text-align:center"><t t-esc="val.get('cuenta_haber')"/></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td style="text-align:center"><t t-esc="val.get('total_haber')"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </t> 
                    </tbody>
```

I want it to be like this
[image: asi]

Comment: You want to add border bottom for each row?

Comment: only after the last tr

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this before. I don't think `tr` can take a border styling directly. My workaround was to style the `td`s in the row:

CSS:

```
tr.border_bottom td {
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
```

Also add `cellspacing="0"` as an attribute to `<table>`. 
and give it style.

Comment: <tr class="border_bottom">

Comment: update my code with the mentioned code but it still comes out the same without the dividing line

Comment: add this style <table style="border-collapse:collapse">

Comment: I could do it using tables with border, now you know how I can make vertical lines?